# "The team is moving around really effectively." Is this a correct use of "effectively"?

Tags: adverbs

Something about this sounds wrong to me. The speaker intends the statement to mean that the team is moving around a lot and it is causing them to succeed.

"The team is moving around really effectively." Correct use of effectively?

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem with 'effectively' here.

Effective means that what you are doing is achieving its intended goals.

When a team moves around, they do so to maintain possession, cover ground and ultimately gain points.

If they are doing this successfully, then their movement is effective.

Hope that helps.

Comment: well, effectively is an adverb, which verb / adj is it affecting

Answer (score 0):

I think the speaker meant:

> The team is moving around really efficiently.

Comment: Efficient does not have the same meaning here. Efficiently would suggest doing something with minimum effort/energy expended. Effectively suggests that what they are doing is enjoying positive results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

> The constant moving makes the team really effective.

They may still not be efficient, though :)